# Using SELECT with UPDATE in the same query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run an UPDATE query on SELECT results but can't figure out how, 
for example - i'm trying to find all numbers in a certain db that start with "888" and out of them i want to change all the results with "999052" to "052".
to get the first part i can use

```
SELECT * FROM `csv_confirmed` WHERE mobile LIKE '999%'
```

This will indeed give me a list of all items that begin with 999. And the following query:

```
UPDATE csv_confirmed SET mobile = REPLACE(mobile, '999052', '052');
```

Would replace all the items that with 999052 into 052 **BUT**, it will not be limited to numbers that begin nor will it limit to the first query results - how do I combine between the two ?

Comment: limit 1 will only limit the results set to 1 (1st result) it wont necessarily match the results i'm aiming at.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp read this it will help you

Comment: i need the 2nd query (UPDATE... ) to run on the 1st query results, i'm not sure how what you suggest helps to my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE csv_confirmed SET mobile = REPLACE(mobile, '999052', '052') WHERE mobile LIKE '999%'
```

Comment: Seems like what i needed, i seems to place "WHERE" in the wrong place in my attempt.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE csv_confirmed SET mobile ='052' WHERE mobile = '999052';
```

You can (and should) add a WHERE clause to an UPDATE to limit its effects.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, the more accurate answer was NoGray's because it contained the "REPLACE" that i needed.

Comment: The REPLACE in NoGray's answer is not required, if what you are doing is changing all values of '999052' to '052'

Comment: I needed to change numbers that START with 888, so without NoGray's WHERE it would change items like 888889999052